# "Randomly" no POST, no boot with new graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I recently bought a new Asus GeForce GTX 1060 dual 6GB  graphics card. After installing it my PC randomly cannot boot.

Sometimes I have to go through cycle of manually turning the PC off with power button and turning it on again like 2 or 3 times before it boots. When this happens there is no post, no beeps and no signal on monitor, black screen. When it finally boots everything seems to work alright, temperatures are low even under heavy load, no flickering or artifacts. Without graphics cards it also works.

There are also two other symptoms.

1. When PC goes to sleep when idle and to hibernation after that, it won't restore. I have to go through powering on and off cycle again.
2. There are some LED lights on the motherboard, and they don't light up when going through this cycle described above.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte GA-Z170-GAMING K3
- GPU: ASUS Geforce GTX 1060 DUAL OC 6GB
- RAM: HyperX 16GB 2400MHz CL12
- Disks: 2 HDDs, 1 SSD
- PSU: SilentiumPC 600W Vero M1 with 80 plus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus certificate
- CPU: Intel i7-6600k

What I have checked already is:

1. Reinstalled video card once again and checked all cables from PSU - one cable, 6+2 pins coming directly from the PSU to the graphics card.
2. Checked if there are any loose screws causing a power shortage.

I didn't try other PCI slots. Graphics card is currently connected to PCI 3.0 16x slot. I used internal graphics for a month before buying card, and it worked fine. After installing the card I switched to external graphics card in the BIOS.

Is the motherboard causing this behavior or is it the graphics card or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For the Nvidia-based graphics cards, installing the driver does not always install all the parts of the driver needed to use just any other Nvidia-based graphics card.  You may need to reinstall the driver, even if it's the same version of the driver.

See here if you need to first download the driver again:

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us